# Will itertools.permutations always return a sorted object?

Tags: python, python-itertools

My problem requires me to iterate through a very large permutation of 10! (or larger) permutations : `a = itertools.permutation(range(10))`

My input range will always be of form range(x) and while I see in almost all cases when I iterate through `a` the permutations are sorted lexicographically 
ie

```
a[0] = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
a[1] = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8)
```

and so on. Is this always a guarantee? 
I do not want to sort it explicitly 
`a = sorted(itertools.permutation(range(10)))`

as that will convert a `<class 'itertools.permutations'>` to `<class 'list'>` which will mean python will try allocating a huge amount of memory which I would like to avoid. For eg

```
a = itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
sys.getsizeof(a)
```

Output
    `232`

```
b = sorted(a)
sys.getsizeof(b)
```

Output
    `3215232`

if this is not a guarantee, what is the alternative?

Comment: This could be answered out by just running some code, can't it? `list(itertools.permutations(reversed(range(3))))`

Comment: I don't want output to be a list

Comment: The `list()` is needed to show the entire permutations sequence, since permutations returns a lazy generator. But list will not change the order, which is deterministic as specified in the docs.

Comment: my questions was does itertools.permutations guarantee  the result is sorted if input is sorted? it has been answered below thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Permutations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is >sorted, the permutation tuples will be produced in sorted order.

So the answer to your question is yes, for an input like `range(x)` the permutations are going to be sorted in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 4):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), we can see that it does indeed return the permutations lexicographically sorted if the input is sorted (which `range(x)` is), and also as an iterable, so you need not worry about the memory allocation as a list

> Permutations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the permutation tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.